# jquery to hide accordion header/title

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, show-hide

I have a template that I'm creating for colleagues to use in a WYSIWYG editor (am a teacher) with an accordion so they can easily add content to each one of them. It will have surplus headers/content for colleagues to use but that doesn't show any that has something like "title_name" as the text of the header.
The HTML is:

```
        <div class="accordion">
           <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header" data-toggle="collapse">
                 <h2 class="card-title">
                    Accordion 1
                 </h2>
              </div>
              <div class="collapse">
                 <div class="card-body">
                    <p>Insert Accordion 1 of 4 content here.</p>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                 <h2 class="card-title">
                    Accordion 2
                 </h2>
              </div>
              <div class="collapse">
                 <div class="card-body">
                    <p>Insert Accordion 2 of 4 content here.</p>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                 <h2 class="card-title">
                    Accordion 3
                </h2>
              </div>
              <div class="collapse">
                 <div class="card-body">
                    <p>Insert Accordion 3 of 4 content here.</p>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h2 class="card-title">
                    title_name
                 </h2>
              </div>
              <div class="collapse">
                 <div class="card-body">
                    <p>Insert Accordion 4 of 4 content here.</p>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
       </div>
```

The jquery that I have is

```
$(".card-header").each(function(){ ($(this).text() === "title_name") ? $(this).hide() : $(this).show()});
```

Help will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :contains of jquery. Since you are having h2 tag inside div of class card-header, jquery is not able to get the text of title_name. I verified this code should work.

```
  $("div.card-header:contains(title_name)").hide();
```

Comment: You are a genius! You have made my day!